# Populate extra database column depending on other column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, auto-populate

I have a database which collects data from an application. And now, I have to create another column that will be populated with predefined data depending on the values in other columns. So, no math, just to look up the values in two other columns and insert the data into the newly added column.

Example

```
id     column1     column2    newColumn
1      15          3          100
```

So when column1 has 15, and column2 has 3, the newColumn should be auto-populated with 100. Again, the number 100 is predifned, not calcualted.

I know I can use triggers for new entries, but the database already has a large amount of data entered, so is there a way to auto populate the newColumn for data that is already tere?

EDIT --------------------------------

So I can use update to populate the column for the records that are already entered ?!

Can i make a trigger which will wait for both values and until both are entered it will return NULL?

Comment: In general it's not a very good idea to store calculated column values. Too often old, inconsistent values will be found. If really needed, triggers are great. But in most cases a view is the best solution to "auto populate"!

Comment: 100 is predifned-- means what do you mean its a random number generator or should be unique please elaborate

Comment: @koushikveldanda I know upfront that when column1 is 15 and column2 is 3, then newColumn has to be 100..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create scalar function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Test] ( @column1 INT, @column2 INT)
RETURNS INT
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @r INT

        IF @column1 = 15 AND @column2 = 3
            SET @r = 100
        ELSE
            SET @r = NULL

        RETURN @r
    END
```

And then add new computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD ColumnName AS dbo.Test(column1, column2) PERSISTED
```

Persisted means, that column is not calculated on the fly, but data is saved.
That's why you used `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. Without binding you can not make the column persisted.

You can also update your current data with simple update statement like in @Rhys Jones answer and add trigger on table like:

```
ALTER TRIGGER trTest ON TableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(column1) AND UPDATE(column2)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE  TableName
            SET     NewColumn = CASE
                                  WHEN column1 = 15 and column2 = 3 then 100
                                  ELSE NULL
                                END
            FROM    Inserted i
                    JOIN TableName t ON t.id = i.id
        END
END
```

Comment: Be aware, that having a computed column persisted (and even having an index on it) doesn't guarantee that the server would not choose to recalculate the value of the column in the queries. In case when such column uses UDF, optimizer will be happily calling UDFs. [A Computed Column Defined with a UDF Might Impact Query Performance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance.aspx) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18716/why-does-sql-server-compute-scalar-when-i-select-a-persisted-computed-column

Comment: @giorgi one question? what if column1 and column2 aren't updated at the same time. I want the trigger to fire when both of this fields have values. Will this UPDATE you wrote work?

Comment: @gogo_rulez, `IF UPDATE(column1) AND UPDATE(column2)` this will fire when both are updated. `IF UPDATE(column1) OR UPDATE(column2)` and this will fire if any of two or both are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a single UPDATE to update the missing values, then use the TRIGGER for new rows.

```
    update MyTable set
        newColumn = case 
                        when column1 = 15 and column2 = 3 then 100
                        when ...
                    end

    where
        newColumn is null
```

However, note what @jarlh says above, there are usually better ways of doing this such as views or computed columns.